# Tickets, dominoes, dice: probability of winning with drawing $7$

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Here is another problem from my probability textbook:

> *A* has a bag of $6$ tickets numbered from $2$ to $7$, *B* has a box of dominoes numbered from double $1$ to double $6$, and *C* has a pair of common dice. *A* draws a ticket from [their] bag, then *B* draws a domino from [their] box, then *C* throws [their] dice, and they continue to do this in order, without replacing ticket or domino, until someone has drawn or thrown $7$, and [they are] declared the winner. Show that their respective chances of winning are $773347: 399303: 378622$.

Alright, here's what I did. For *A* it's got to be$${1\over6} + \left({5\over6}\right)\left({{25}\over{28}}\right)\left({5\over6}\right)\left({1\over5}\right) + \left({5\over6}\right)\left({{25}\over{28}}\right)\left({5\over6}\right)\left({4\over5}\right)\left({{24}\over{27}}\right)\left({{5\over6}}\right)\left({1\over4}\right) + \ldots$$And at this point I gave up, I don't see an easy way to evaluate this without writing it all out - same goes for *B* and *C*. Clearly the sums for each *A*, *B*, *C* are not infinite since we don't replace *A*'s tickets or *B*'s dominoes, but these sums are ugly, big, and huge, so given that the proportions of their respective chances of winning are **relatively** small, I am wondering if there is a clever way to to get those ratios without having to brute force the calculations naively.

Comment: When you draw a domino, how do you get $7$ if they are double $1$ to double $6$? I am not very familiar with it so checking.

Comment: @MathLover I was going to ask the same question, and I definitely think that the OP (i.e.original poster) needs to respond.  While waiting, my guess is that this is similar to a regular set of $(28)$ dominoes, except that the $(7)$  dominoes with blank faces have been removed, leaving $(21)$ dominoes.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks. I also notice that in their work, OP is using $28$ in the denominator.

Comment: @MathLover Then either the OP has misinterpreted the phrase "box of dominoes numbered from double 1 to double 6", or misquoted the problem, or the problem composer intends $28$ dominoes and mis-stated the problem.

Comment: Thanks all. I'm actually not sure. There was a previous problem in the book that said double $1$ to double $6$ which I assumed had $21$, and then it turned out it was assumed to have $28$. But this textbook is known to have lots of bizarre typos/assumptions that are wrong, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @EmperorConcerto You are absolutely right, I misinterpreted the problem.  I totally overlooked the phrase "...without replacing ticket or domino...".  My answer/approach, which I have now deleted, would be correct if all sampling is done *with* *replacement*, since if all three people fail, the conditions would then be identical to the start of the competition.  Since that is the case (in effect) for the dice thrower, but not the case for the other two people, my approach **can not work**.  I will give up and let someone else try.

Comment: For what it's worth, as I understand it, there are either $21$ dominoes or $28$ dominoes.  In either case, only $3$ of these dominoes *add* *up* *to* *7*.

Comment: Given the assigned goal : "Show that their respective chances of winning are 773347:399303:378622" I suspect that you are doing what was intended.  Actually, since you only have to contend with 5 full rounds (or the 1st player wins), the math is not that bad **with a calculator**.  The only thing that I would suggest is that you calculate the chances of the $n$ rounds resulting in no wins (yet), for each value of $n$ in $\{1,2,3,4,5\}.$  Denoting this as $f(n)$, you will find that you can use $f(n)$ to compute $f(n+1)$.  This should shortcut the work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that the dominoes $B$ has to choose from are the $21$ without any blank faces. By my calculation this would produce the relative chances given as the answer.

Following the procedure suggested by [user2661923](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/464411/user2661923) in the comments, let $\ f_0=1\ $,
$\ f_1\ $ be the probability that no-one wins in round $1$, and, for $\ i=2,3,\dots,6\ $, $\ f_i\ $ the conditional probability that no-one wins in round $\ i\ $ given that no-one has won in any of the previous $\ i-1\ $ rounds. Then
\begin{align}
f_i&=\frac{5(6-i)(19-i)}{6(7-i)(22-i)}\\
P\big(\text{$A$ wins in round $i$}\big)&=\frac{\prod_\limits{k=0}^{i-1}f_k}{7-i}\ ,\\
P\big(\text{$A$ wins}\big)&=\sum_{i=1}^6\frac{\prod_\limits{k=0}^{i-1}f_k}{7-i}\ ,\\
P\big(\text{$B$ wins in round $i$}\big)&=\frac{3(6-i)\prod_\limits{k=0}^{i-1}f_k}{(22-i)(7-i)}\ ,\\
P\big(\text{$B$ wins}\big)&=\sum_{i=1}^6\frac{3(6-i)\prod_\limits{k=0}^{i-1}f_k}{(22-i)(7-i)}\ ,\\
P\big(\text{$C$ wins in round $i$}\big)&=\frac{(19-i)(6-i)\prod_\limits{k=0}^if_k}{6(22-i)(7-i)}\ ,\\
P\big(\text{$C$ wins}\big)&=\sum_{i=1}^6\frac{(19-i)(6-i)\prod_\limits{k=0}^if_k}{6(22-i)(7-i)}\ .\\
\end{align}
Here is some [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au) code to carry out the calculation:

```
pa:=0;
pb:=0;
pc:=0;
f:=1;
for i in [1..6] do
    pa:=pa+f/(7-i);
    pb:=pb+3*(6-i)*f/((22-i)*(7-i));
    pc:=pc+(19-i)*(6-i)*f/(6*(22-i)*(7-i));
    f:=5*(19-i)*(6-i)*f/(6*(22-i)*(7-i));
 end for;
 print pa,pb,pc,pa+pb+pc;
```

If you copy and paste this into the [online Magma calculator](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc) it returns the values
\begin{align}
P\big(\text{$A$ wins}\big)&=\frac{773347}{1551312}\\
P\big(\text{$B$ wins}\big)&=\frac{14789}{57456}=
\frac{399303}{1551312}\\
P\big(\text{$C$ wins}\big)&=\frac{189331}{775656}=\frac{378622}{1551312}\ .
\end{align}